# Data transaction between PHP and client - which way?

Tags: php

I'll going to keep my question short. Which way sounds more professional?

This?

```
PHP:
echo '<li>Link 1</li>';
echo '<li>Link 2</li>';
echo '<li>Link 3</li>';

jQuery:
for each <li>, add hover effect
```

or this?

```
PHP:
echo json_decode(array('Link 1', 'Link 2', Link 3'));

jQuery:
Encode json value, extract values, add hover effect
```

or XML instead of JSON?

I'm asking this because I'm getting bored of coding repetitive things. I want things to be bridged so a JSON/XML standart seems a bit better for me.

What do you think? How can I improve this logic if I want my websites to be bridged?

Ps. Sorry if I couldn't explain myself well. Basically, my a.com website may want to use my b.com's news, so a standart while transacting/pulling these datas would be better. I'm not sure what other alternatives do I have, though.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding it in JSON is better, this way  if you need to create a web service / api that other applications access (such as an iphone app, android app, whatever) it is easy to decode.
You should be doing json_encode on the PHP side, and then decode it javascript side, not other way around

I don't understand why XML is as popular as it is.. I love working with JSON, it is so easy to use since it is object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

If the end client is a generic person (i.e. an end user, like us), they likely *don't care*.  In that scenario, write your data transaction in the most efficient and easiest-to-maintain form possible - JSON is a good option.

If the end client is another entity (i.e. a news aggregator or otherwise large repository of text), they likely *care very much* as to how you acquire/use their data.  You would have to rely on their API and how they expose data to you.  You can't just say that you want your data in JSON or XML if they don't support that - and there are sites out there that consider it a violation of terms to scrape their content, so be careful about that, too.

Comment: I don't pull news from external sources. I pull news from my secondary website, so I can use JSON/XML or even a use-ready HTML output. I just want things to be bridged, so if I make a third website soon, I want to reach news data in a standarded way. For example, if I do a HTML output, what if I don't want these <li> values? It would be headache to replace these <li> values on my third website. I think you got me this time. I just don't know what is the most professional way to carry datas with least future headaches.

Comment: Well, it depends.  JSON is nice for serializing objects and data, and XML is the basis of RSS feeds, which are still prevalent on the 'net.  It boils down to if you want to support RSS or JSON, which is really a personal choice slightly more than a professional need.